# "Xorg" process does not take limits from /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: xorg, ps, pam, limit

I have this in my `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
#<domain>   <type>  <item>         <value>
root        -       memlock     65536
root        -       stack       524288
root        -       nice        -20
root        -       nofile      16384
```

yet, the process `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`, which does run as root still has only `1024` for `RLIMIT_NOFILE`:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep Xorg)/limits | grep 'open file'
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

Why are my settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` not reflected in `Xorg` ?
Where can I increase limits for `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` ?

My system is Debian Buster without `systemd` (I am using `sysvinit`). And I am using `slim` as login manager. So I guess it is `slim`, that launches `Xserver`. Below is the `pam` module used by `slim`:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/slim
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-auth
@include common-account

session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so

@include common-session
@include common-password
```

## UPDATE

Inspired by suggestion from `@ajgringo619`, I have added `ulimit -n 16384` to `/etc/init/slim.conf`, the configuration script used by `slim`, since it is `slim` that actually starts `xserver`:

At first, it looked as if that solved the problem, after adding `ulimit -n 16384` and restarting slim, the new ulimit takes effect. But the problem is, after restart, it does not. I mean, I have to manually restart slim for the new ulimits to take effects. if slim starts as a niormal init script, it still has the old ulimit value `1024`.

Comment: What happens if you login as root and run a process? Are the limits applied then?

Comment: How is Xorg started on your system (via `xdm`, `gdm3`, `startx`, etc)? What kind of system is it (Linux with/out systemd, etc)?

Comment: @ajgringo619 - when I log in as root (from the console), the limits are applied.

Comment: @mosvy - I am using `Debian Buster` without `systemd`, and `slim` as login manager.

Comment: Are limits applied to processes started from Xorg (eg a terminal window)? If so, please could you help us understand why you need Xorg itself to have the limits changed (raised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated to reflect your test)

Since the user that's running the Xorg process is not actually logging in, your settings in **/etc/security/limits.conf** are being ignored. With sysvinit, you need to add **ulimit -n 16384** to the beginning of `/etc/init.d/slim` (tested on antiX 19), not in `slim.conf`.

The systemd version of this fix also works; tested on my Debian 10 VM (adding a configuration setting that mimicked the aforementioned ulimit command).

Comment: please see my update.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: that fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

can't comment now, so Answer as a suggestion here.

you can try:

```
root        soft       nofile      16333
root        hard       nofile      16888
```

make sure to `relogin` or restart `Xorg`, then check:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep Xorg)/limits | grep 'open file'
```